# Grunt - Unable to Read Json File After Powershell ConvertTo-Json

Tags: powershell, gruntjs, powershell-3.0

I have a really strange problem at the moment.

I am creating list of files that my grunt-cache-breaker uses. I generate the list of files using this powershell script:

```
$ScriptDir = Split-Path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path

$file = @{}

#GET HTML FILES
$Dir = get-childitem $ScriptDir\Helix -recurse 
$file = $Dir | where {$_.extension -eq ".html" } | % {$_.FullName}
#END

$file | convertto-jSon | out-file $ScriptDir\htmlfiles.json
```

this produces a file with contains something like this

```
[
  "C:\\test\test1.html",
  "C:\\test\test1.html",
  "C:\\test\test1.html"
]
```

my Cache Breaker code is:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
grunt.initConfig({
    listOfHtmlPaths: grunt.file.readJSON('htmlfiles.json'),
    cachebreaker: {
        dev: {
            options: {
                match: ['.js', '.css', 'min.css'],
                src:
                { path: 'Helix/**/*' }
            },
        files:
            { src: ['<%= listOfHtmlPaths %>'], }
        },
    },
});
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-cache-breaker');
grunt.registerTask('default', ['cachebreaker']);
};
```

After I run the powershell I then run Grunt but I get the following error:

Error: Unable to parse "bustAFile.json" file (Unexpected token ?).

If I copy the entire contents of the bustAFile.json into a new notepad file change nothing at all save it. It works.

Is Poweshell adding some strange encoding that I can't see ?

Answer (score 1):

forcing the powershell to output in ASCII encoding fixed my problem

```
$file | convertto-jSon -Compress | out-file $ScriptDir\bustAFile.json -encoding ascii
```

it appears that Grunt cannot read other encodings when parsing JSON.